# set number in button using vb 2008

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i have problem in my record database. why when click btnOut. system will save status=1
please anyone help me. to set number in button. this is code, please check if any error. thank.

I'm using vb 2008 and databse mysql

form 1

```vb
Private Sub btnIn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnIn.Click
    Const btnIn As Integer = 1
    Form1.Show()
End Sub'

Private Sub btnOut_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOut.Click
    Const btnO As Integer = 0
    Form1.Show()
End Sub
```

Form 2

```
Private Sub btnD_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnD.Click
    Dim command As MySqlCommand
    command = New MySqlCommand
    Const btnO As Integer = 0
    Const btnI As Integer = 1


    command.CommandText = "SEARCH INTO visitor WHERE nokp VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "')"

    If TextBox1.Text = "Masukkan No.I/C Anda" Or TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Sila Masukkan No Kad Pengenalan Anda", "Mesej", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

    Else
        If btnO = 0 Then
            command.Connection = conn
            tkhupd = Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:tt")
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO visitor(nok,tkhupd,status)VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & tkhupd & "','" & 1 & "' )"
            MessageBox.Show("ok")
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            TextBox1.ResetText()

        Else
            If btnO = 0 Then
                command.Connection = conn
                tkhupd = Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:tt")
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO visitor(nok,tkhupd,status)VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & tkhupd & "','" & 1 & "' )"
                MessageBox.Show("ok Out")
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                TextBox1.ResetText()
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: There you go with those sql injection vulnerabilities again. I posted an example to one of your questions yesterday that demonstrated query parameters.  **This is important.**

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say it, but there's just so much wrong in that code. Don't even get me started on the sql injection vulnerabilities (right now, you're just asking to get hacked). No, I'll go even more basic. Look at these two lines from your sample:

```vb
Const btnO As Integer = 0
'...
If btnO = 0 Then
  '...
Else 
  '...
End If
```

btnO is a **constant**.  It can't change. It will *always* be 0. Therefore, your If/Then check is just play silly: it will always be true. Anything you put in the Else block is worthless: the code can *never* run.